# numpy matrix string with python3.4

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i'm having trouble with 3.4 using numpy. My question is to know how can i have a numpy matrix with plain string format instead byte-string.

```
def res(data):
    M = np.zeros(data.shape).astype(dtype='|S20')
    lines,columns = M.shape
    for l in range(lines):
        M[l][0] = data[l][1]
        M[l][1] = data[l][2]
        M[l][2] = data[l][3]  
    return M
**result python2.7**
[['Ann' '38.72' '-9.133']
 ['John' '55.68' '12.566']
 ['Richard' '52.52' '13.411']
 ['Alex' '40.42' '-3.703']]

**result python3.4**
[[b'Ann' b'38.72' b'-9.133']
 [b'John' b'55.68' b'12.566']
 [b'Richard' b'52.52' b'13.411']
 [b'Alex' b'40.42' b'-3.703']]
```

In Python3.4 How can i have my Matrix in plain string like in example for python2.7 this is bad because i have functions that expect string values and not byte-strings.

Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: Generally with a 2d array, it's better index with `M[l,0]`.  As to your problem, the base string type in 3.4 is unicode, while in 2.7 it's ascii.  So for some purposes `b'abc'` is the 3.4 equivalent, but for other just type `str`.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the solution were simply to change `dtype('|S20')` to `dtype(str)`..I hope this help.